# Network-wide use of bandwidth

Tags: networking, router

I've got a metered connection (monthly data quota) via a cellular provider.

There are a handful of devices on the local network (a laptop or two, two desktops, a phone, a tablet, etc.). The router is a Novatel T1114; there's a TP-Link switch (TL-SF1008P) that's connected to it.

How can I get a network-wide perspective on what's using my monthly quota?  Because the majority of devices connect wirelessly, the switch will only get me a slice of the picture. And I'd like to avoid piecing together data from different applications on different platforms.

Comment: If your switch supports SNMP, this is how you would monitor it.

Comment: Also, you can use a routing platform like pfsense/opensense to not only monitor. But assign a total per month cap that would deny client devices access after the specified cap.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the manual for the T1114 device, it does not seem likely that you can do this kind of monitoring on it.

This means you either need additional hardware, or to delegate separate monitoring to each individual device on your network and trust there are no rogue devices, or you need to put another box between your T1114 and your switch - and ensure that this other box handles the WIFI connections.

Its often a good idea to look at a box capable of running DD-WRT, as this gives you a lot of control of your network, including (out the box) showing the Wireless network clients connected and their connection speed, and a list of all the devices and MAC and IP addresses.   Using Status -> bandwidth will show you the usage per interface which, depending on how its setup can show where to look for data usage.   Unfortunately this does not show usage per port/IP - however this can be done using tcpdump or any number of scripts or plugins to help (not trivial, but at least doable), for example using a port of [bwmon](https://github.com/vortex-5/ddwrt-bwmon).